# Как добавить пользовательское поле при создании новой группы в wordpress buddypress?

Tags: wordpress

Как добавить пользовательское поле при создании новой группы в buddypress?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Есть плагин для этой цели: [BuddyPress Groups Extras](https://wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress-groups-extras/)